# Leading prayer when one has drank alcohol in the past

Tags: salat, alcohol

I have question concerning alcohol and leading a prayer (for congregational prayer). I know that one's prayers are not accepted for 40 days from the point that person has drunk alcohol (i.e. they are not rewarded). But what if that person leads a prayer during that period? Will the prayer of the muslims following this person be accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I got an answer from an islam QA page:

"The prayer of the followers will be accepted.
However, it is Makrooh-Tahrimi to make a person who drinks alcohol an Imam."

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. As in the given case the "imam" stopped drinking and repented days before leading a prayer.